# TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function

Tags: node.js

Не могу понять, в чем проблема.

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const config = require('./config/config')

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

const app = express()

app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(require('./routes/posts'))

mongoose.connect(config.dbURL, config.dbOptions)

mongoose.connection
  .once('open', () => {
    console.log(`Mongoose - successful connection ...`)
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || config.port,
      () => console.log(`Server start on port ${config.port} ...`))
  })
  .on('error', error => console.warn(error))
```

Запрашиваемый файл с 15 строки (posts.js)

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Post = require('../models/post-model')

router.post('/posts', (req, res) => {
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description
  })
  post.save((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.send({
        success: true,
        message: `Post with ID_${data._id} saved successfully!`
      })
    }
  })
})
```

И подробно текст ошибки

```
TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
    at Function.use (C:\Users\andre\Desktop\Обучение\Practice\mevn\server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\andre\Desktop\Обучение\Practice\mevn\server\src\index.js:15:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:596:3)
```

Comment: У вас post.js ничего не экспортирует. Соответственно, выражение `app.use(require('post.js'))` здесь будет равносильно `app.use({})`. Естественно, что express'у это не нравится.

Comment: Да, я с делал экспорт как Post, консоль не выдает ошибок, но по url ничего не загружается, просто бесконечная загрузка. Если экспортировать в любую другую переменную, то приложение крашится.

Comment: @Андрей роутер нужно экспортировать, а не модель Post. `module.exports = router;` добавьте в конец. Ну и в ситуации, когда `save()` вернула ошибку нужно тоже вызывать res.send()  - либо ошибку отправлять, либо текст какой. Поэтому у вас коннект и висит.